Chat History Fetched from Cloud Firestore Not Displaying in React Frontend
Problem:
Despite successful data fetching and processing, the chats do not appear in the UI. Could someone point out what might be going wrong or suggest any debugging steps?
I'm working on a web app where I fetch Q&A chat history from a Cloud Firestore database and display it on the frontend. The chats are retrieved successfully (confirmed via Network tab in browser dev tools), but they are not displayed in my app.
Backend Code:
I have a Flask endpoint to fetch chat history:
@application.route('/chat-history', methods=['POST'])
def get_user_chat_history():
    user_id = request.json['user_id']
    document_id = request.json['document_id']

    if not user_id or not document_id:
        return jsonify({"error": "Missing required parameters: user and document"}), 400

    user_chats_ref = db.collection("ChatHistory").document(user_id).collection(str(document_id)).document("chats")

    try:
        chat_doc = user_chats_ref.get()

        if not chat_doc.exists:
            return jsonify({"error": "No chat history found"}), 404

        chat_data = chat_doc.to_dict()
        chat_array = chat_data.get('chat', [])

        sorted_chat_array = sorted(chat_array, key=lambda x: float(x['timestamp']), reverse=True)

        return jsonify(sorted_chat_array), 200

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error fetching chat history for user {user_id}: {e}')
        return jsonify({"error": "Error fetching chat history"}), 500

Frontend Code (React):
Here’s the React code where I attempt to display the fetched chats:
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        navigate("/login");
      }
    });
    populateChat();
    return () => unsubscribe();
}, []);

async function populateChat() {
    const response = await fetch(`${baseurl}/chat-history`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            user_id: uid,
            document_id: profileName,
        }),
    });

    try {
        const data = await response.json();
        const transformData = (data) => {
            const transformed = [];

            data.forEach((item) => {
                for (const key in item) {
                    item[key].forEach((entry) => {
                        if (entry.question) {
                            transformed.push({ user: "user", message: entry.question });
                        }
                        if (entry.answer) {
                            transformed.push({ user: "bot", message: entry.answer });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            return transformed;
        };
        const transformedData = transformData(data);
        const firstFiveTexts = transformedData.slice(0, 6);
        // Assuming you are setting the state somewhere here to update the UI with firstFiveTexts
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching chat history:', error);
    }
}

What I've Tried:

Verified that the backend returns the correct data structure.
Confirmed data fetch success through the browser’s Network tab.
Ensured that populateChat function runs and processes the data.


From your debugging we know your backend works, and that your client makes the request properly.
Within the frontend, have you tried printing the response value you get in the code? maybe you are accessing the data wrong because you expected it in a different format etc.
you know its reaching the clientside, now you need to see where the issue is at client side.

browser gets it, so check that your code accesses it properly
hard code fake data in the format you expect, to see your UI is able to display correctly if it does receive data

I expect you are accessing the data wrong, for example you expect an array of chat messages [msg, msg]
and its actually {data: [msg,msg]} etc.
Narrow down where the issue is, then keep narrowing it down, for example if you see hard coding works, you know its in how you get the data from the request (that you know returns valid data)
